# Unable to call virtual methods inherited through two classes

Tags: c++

I have tried to create a class which inherits from another class, which in turn inherits from another, abstract class with only pure virtual methods:

```
// objects.cpp:

class Object
{
public:
    virtual void generate() = 0;
    virtual ~Object() = 0;
};

class Vehicle: public Object
{
    virtual void generate() = 0;
protected:
  // Attributes inherited by Bike objects.
public:
    virtual ~Vehicle() = 0;

};

class Bike: public Vehicle
{
private:
  // Attributes specific to Bike class objects.
public:
    void generate()
    {
      // Takes the data from the object being called on and writes them to a file.
    }
    Bike()
    {
      // Declaring a bike launches the constructor which randomly generates and assigns data.
    }
    ~Bike() {}

};
void trigger_generation(Object & opoint)
{
    opoint.generate();
}
```

Here's the header file:

```
// objects.hpp

#ifndef OBJECTS_H
#define OBJECTS_H

class Object
{
public:
    virtual void generate();
    virtual ~Object();
};

class Vehicle: public Object
{
protected:
  // Attributes inherited by Bike objects.
public:
    virtual ~Vehicle();

};

class Bike: public Vehicle
{
private:
  // Attributes specific to Bike class objects.
public:
    void generate();
    Bike();
    ~Bike();
};

void trigger_generation(Object & opoint);

#endif // OBJECTS_H
```

And then, in the main.cpp file I run the generate() method on a Bike class object:

```
// main.cpp
#include "objects.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Bike itsactuallyabicycle;
    trigger_generation(itsactuallyabicycle);

}
```

I end up with these errors:
`` main.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `Bike::Bike()'

main.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `Bike::~Bike()'

main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `Bike::~Bike()' ``

What is causing these errors and how do I get around them so that the Bike class methods can be called normally?

EDIT: Compiled using `g++ main.cpp objects.hpp objects.cpp`

Comment: Can you edit the compiler/linker commands you used into the question?

Comment: You seem to have defined the class twice - once in the header and once in the .cpp file. That won't work.

Comment: You have declarations of your classes in both objects.hpp header file and objects.cpp source file.  You may have better luck right now having everything in your main.cpp file, because it appears you have not learned how to split up the code into separate files yet.

Comment: @NeilButterworth — it would work if the definitions were the same. But keeping the two definitions in synch would be a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure virtual destructor is legal in C++ but it must have a body.

```
 Object::~Object()
 {

 }
```

and

```
 Vehicle::~Vehicle()
 {

 }
```

Comment: I would not put those `cout` complaints in the destructor bodies.  They WILL be called when an object of a concrete derived class is destroyed.

Comment: @aschepler, Respect your advice and comment. I have modified my answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [class.ctor/1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#1.2)

> The class-name shall not be a typedef-name. In a constructor
>   declaration, each decl-specifier in the optional decl-specifier-seq
>   shall be friend, inline, explicit, or constexpr.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>    S();      // declares the constructor
> };
>
> S::S() { }   // defines the constructor
> ```
>
> — end example ]

```
Bike itsactuallyabicycle;
```

will call the declaration in your `hpp` file which are:

```
Bike();
~Bike();
```

Thus, `Bike();` and `~Bike();` are just declarations and not definitions causing:

```
undefined reference to `Bike::Bike()'
undefined reference to `Bike::~Bike()'
```

Comment: Am I supposed to define the cons-/destructors in the header file with the namespace syntax "e.g.: Bike::Bike() {}" or in the cpp file? And can't I just use a single definition instruction?